# Missing bigcommerce default css after upload bundle successfully

Tags: bigcommerce, stencils

After uploaded without error bigcommerce stencil theme bundle, but default **theme.css** file not loading.

After click source **css/theme.css** link, got below error:

```
{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found"}
```

**Note:** working my custom **.css** file online and locally, but default `theme.css` file not loading in online, but locally ok.

Need your assistance, Please

Regards,

Comment: Someone please help, I have done project my localy but after upload bundle then got this issue. please help

Comment: After Create any stencil theme bundle then missing CSS, any idea, please?? 

i have also check  with stencil default theme just change name from config.json but same issue.

 Need your assistance, Please

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to run stencil bundle on windows 10 and upload it to Big Commerce. The only thing that worked for me, since I didn't have a mac, was:

1. Install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS via Oracle VM Virtual box.
2. Run Ubuntu and install nvm.
3. Install node 4.1.2 via nvm (not as sudo).
4. Install stencil framework and theme (not as sudo)
5. Run stencil bundle, and upload the zip to test. If the css is loading correctly, then you are good to go.